# In powershell, is there a way to transfer data on the pipe while a Cmdlet is still running?

Tags: windows, powershell, youtube-dl

I am attempting to make the tool **youtube-dl** write a progress bar when it downloads a video. The issue I am having appears to be caused by the data that I am piping not being piped until the downloader finishes executing. Is there a way to make the data send through the pipe on a newline?

**To recreate:**

I wrote a function to filter the output of youtube-dl so the download progress lines will be sent to a progress bar, while the rest are passed to the output. The progress bar only shows up for a moment at the end, and none of the next that should passthrough does.

```
Function Write-ProgressBar
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$InputString,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Type
    )

    $regex = "\[download\] *(\d{0,3}[.]{0,1}\d{0,3})% of ([0-9.\/BGKMTbikst]+)* at *([0-9.\/BGKMTbikst]+)* *ETA (\d*:\d*).*?" 
    $IsDownloadProgress = $InputString -match $regex

    if ($IsDownloadProgress)
    {
        $Size = $Matches[2]
        $Speed = $Matches[3]
        $ETA = $Matches[4]
        $PercentComplete = $Matches[1]

        $SecondsLeft = $(([int]$ETA.split(':')[0]*60)+[int]$ETA.split(':')[1])

        Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading $Type" -Status "Downloading $Size file at $Speed" -SecondsRemaining $SecondsLeft -PercentComplete $PercentComplete
    } else {
        Write-Output $InputString
    }
}

youtube-dl.exe -o "C:\users\public\videos\%(title)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ -f bestaudio -i -x | Write-ProgressBar -Type "Audio"
```

Write-ProgressBar creates the expected progress bar when used inside of a loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -le 100; $i++) {
    "[download]  $i% of 58.26MiB at  1.04MiB/s ETA 00:$(100-$i)" | Write-ProgressBar -Type "test"
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
}
```

But when the output from the same loop is sent to the pipe from a function, the progress bar will only appear for a moment when the function returns:

```
Function test-pipe
{
    for ($i = 0; $i -le 100; $i++) {
        Write-Output "[download]  $i% of 58.26MiB at  1.04MiB/s ETA 00:$(100-$i)"
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
    }
}

test-pipe | Write-ProgressBar -Type "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your function.
Try after pipeline %{ } :

```
& youtube-dl -o 'C:\users\public\videos\%(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ -f bestaudio -i -x | %{ $_ | Write-ProgressBar -Type 'Audio'}
```